# Dragging behavior is not working for items in ItemsControl: MouseDragElementBehavior

Tags: wpf, drag, itemscontrol

I have a class

```
public class DrawingCanvas : FrameworkElement
```

which uses MouseDragElementBehavior to implement **dragging**.

I want to drag the DrawingCanva like a layer in Photoshop relative to another layer

Working alone with (XAML on pic #1)

```
<Grid x:Name="_layoutRootControl">
    <Canvas
        Grid.Column="0">
        <canvas:DrawingCanvas />
        <canvas:DrawingCanvas />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

do allows dragging, but when I place **DrawingCanvas** inside **ItemsControl**
and bind **ItemsSource** to collection of items, draggins doesn't work.
(XAML on pic #2)

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=LayersViewModel.Layers}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <canvas:DrawingCanvas />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I don't understand why.

First case is the following XAML structure:

[image: First case]

And the second case is the following XAML structure:

[image: Second case]

**Update:**

I've found out that in second case with ItemsControl a DrawingCanvas.Parent = null

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail?  What are you trying to drag, items within `DrawingCanvas`, or the `DrawingCanvas` itself?  Can you also provide the XAML of your `ItemsControl`?

Comment: Yes, I will update the topic with more details

Comment: I've found out that in second case with ItemsControl DrawingCanvas.Parent = null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In connection with that item.Parent inside ItemsControls is always null

I've found the solution in the following topics with explanation:

[Why does the Parent property of a container of an ItemsControl return null and not the Panel it sits on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118414/why-does-the-parent-property-of-a-container-of-an-itemscontrol-return-null-and-n)

[Combining ItemsControl with draggable items - Element.parent always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902392/combining-itemscontrol-with-draggable-items-element-parent-always-null)

**Update:**

Now the Parent is not null, still the problem remains.

**Update 2**

The last lacking thing
I had to define "**extenders:DragHelper.CanDrag**" inside ContentPresenter instead of

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The resulting template is as follows, so the issue is solved:

```
<ItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=LayersViewModel.Layers}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property=**"extenders:DragHelper.CanDrag"** Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <surfaces:DrawingCanvas />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: May I ask where that DragHelper came from? I found it neither in the .NET 4.5 Framework nor in the Behavior SDK from Blend..

Comment: DragHelper is from my code. Found it here, on stackoverflow

Comment: @Dmitry can you provide the code for the DragHelper?